# C++ Proxy DLL (64-Bit)

Tags: c++, assembly, proxy, 64-bit

I used a tool called wrappit to generate proxy dll files.
The tool can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically

But the target DLL is compiled as a 64bit and because Visual Studio doesn't support 64-bit inline assembly, and am unaware of any other options, I am unable to go further.

This is one function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __stdcall __E__312__()
{
__asm
    {
    jmp p[312*4];
    }
}
```

Naked/inline asm is not supported and give compiler errors.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no inline asm in x64 world, and even if you find some substitution (intrinsics?), there
is no support for  __declspec(naked) as well

What exactly are you trying to do?
Are you trying to intercept some call in foreign (for you) DLL?

If this is the case, there is thing from Microsoft called Detours, heard it is pretty good, never use it

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

You might want to look at MinHook as an alternative, this one is good

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am creating a proxy DLL using the tool I mentioned (Wrappit) - the source code I sent is a part of that generated code. The proxy DLL exports all functions that the original DLL has.

Comment: Well, being out of luck with inline asm and __declspec(naked), you have to use other way to build trampolines. I would guess using upper part of Proxy-DLL to build list of exported functions (.DEF) together with part of MinHook which builds trampolines might work. But that's not a trivial project by itself. Sorry, have nothing more to offer...

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can intercept any function with [Deviare in-proc](https://github.com/nektra/Deviare-InProc/) as Detours alternative. It works perfect in both x86 and x64, it's open source and it's well maintained.